# How can I use a password manager to log on to Windows with a Live ID?

Tags: windows, passwords, login

I use a Microsoft Live ID as the primary user account on my home PC (Windows 8.1) and I've recently started using KeePass for managing complex web site passwords. Because I use my Live ID for outlook.com, OneDrive, and all things Microsoft, I'd like to apply a new, complex, KeePass-generated password to that account but it seems like this would make logging into my home PC rather cumbersome.

Other than reverting to the use of a local Windows account, are there any solutions for combining Windows logon, Live ID, a complex password, and a password manager?

Comment: I think Windows 8.1 allowed pin login, your not going to be able to integrate Keepass, in order to use it to log you in.

Comment: The idea is good, but the problem is that the Windows logon screen is a very sensitive part of Windows, so AFAIK is not a part that you can access of modify programmatically like other parts of the system (imagine the security concerns if you could). Windows *do* support alternative and/or extra requirements for login like smart cards, but I think that it must be directly supported by Microsoft, because IIRC doing that involve substituting the logon component of Windows with a custom one. If you upgrade to Windows 10, you can try [two factor authentication](https://duo.com/docs/rdp).

Comment: @AlbertoMartinez While not necessarily a good idea, it is possible to replace "C:\Windows\System32\osk.exe" or any one of the other accessibility executables with KeePass.exe, and use the accessibility menu to activate that accessibility feature, thereby allowing you to login to windows using a password manager.

Comment: @Ploni Windows executable are digitally signed, I'm almost sure that Windows would complain if you replace a system executable with another different (or it would just restore the original one).

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into using Windows Hello? You need a Webcam for Facial Recognition finger print reader for well fingerprints. etc. Finger print readers can start at about $20

A bit more on Windows Hello:
*Hello goes beyond logins. With Passport, Microsoft hopes to replace the passwords you use for applications, websites, and intranet login with the aforementioned biometric data. Passport isn’t new – it’s a feature of Microsoft’s online accounts – but the company will soon open it to IT managers, developers, and web authors. Belifore says that Passport will eventually makes its way to “your favorite commerce sites, email and social networking services, financial institutions, business networks and more.”*

https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/login-to-windows-10-with-your-face-thanks-to-windows-hello/

Select the Start  button, then select Settings  > Accounts  > Sign-in options  to set up Windows Hello. Under Windows Hello , you’ll see options for face, fingerprint, or iris if your PC has a fingerprint reader or a camera that supports it. Once you’re set up, you’ll be able to sign in with a quick swipe or glance.